# Where is the .exe in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am new to programming my own apps, since I used to work on old programs on the pc. Is there a file like the .exe in my old programs? Little backround information: I need to execute the app on a phone without a physical connection and without the typical appstores. In my imagination I can store something like the release file online and my users can download it?

Thanks for teaching me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the community! On Android, the file you are looking for is called an APK, you can take that file and install it on other devices easily. For iOS it's a bit more complicated and you can't share the IPA files and install them as for android, you are confined to using a physical device or sending it over using testflight, which is provided by Apple for testers.

You can find those APK files inside your project's folder in the following path:
`build/app/outputs/flutter-apk`

Comment: Ahh thanks for the answer. So lets say I uploud the file on a server then the user clicks on the apk-file on his device and the app gets opened? Is it this easy... At leas for android?

Comment: It is that easy for android, but you need to be aware of the different types of builds. There are release builds and debug builds, and you have to account for certain changes be tween both versions. Before distributing your app, you should test the release build on other physical devices first, and make sure everything is working as you intended, especially regarding internet connection issues or Firebase.